# Php code works in Chrome, IE but not Firefox

Tags: php

I have written a php code to decode a certificate and list its contents. I'm unable to understand what is the problem with the following code. The code is working fine with Chrome and IE but not in firefox. I have cleared the browser cache and stilling not getting expected output on all machines. Please help me.

Note: I do understand that this is purely server side activity, but still none of the clients are providing expected decoded output for Firefox browser

cert.php

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <textarea id="cert_input" name="cert_input" rows="10" wrap="hard"
              value="<?= isset($_POST['cert_input']) ?>" /></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="submit_button" value="Decode" id="submit_button" />
</form>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit_button'])) {
    echo '<font face="Tahoma" size="2" ></br></br>';
    echo '<font color="#747474">Certificate Details:</br></font>';
    $str = $_POST['cert_input'];
    $cert = openssl_x509_parse($str);


    $validFrom = date('r', $cert['validFrom_time_t']);
    $validTo = date('r', $cert['validTo_time_t']);

    function days_Apart($start, $end) {
        $start_ts = strtotime($start);
        $end_ts = strtotime($end);
        $diff = $end_ts - $start_ts;
        return round($diff / 86400);

    }

    $remaining_days = days_Apart($validFrom, $validTo);

    if ($remaining_days > 0) {
        $status = 'Active';
        echo "<table id='minimal' style='border:1px solid #4dff4d;background-color:#f5fff5;'>";
    }
    else {
        $status = 'Expired';
        echo "<table id='minimal' style='border:1px solid #ff3300;background-color:#ffefef;'>";
    }


    echo "
    <tr>
        <td>COMMON NAME [CN]</td>
        <td>" . $cert['subject']['CN'] . "</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ORGANISATION [O]</td>
        <td>" . $cert['subject']['O'] . "</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ORGANISATION UNIT [OU]</td>
        <td>" . $cert['subject']['OU'] . "</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>LOCALITY [L]</td>
        <td>" . $cert['subject']['L'] . "</td>
    </tr>
    </table>";
    echo '</font>';
}
?>
```

Output from Firefox-
[image: Firefox Output]

Comment: php code runs on server. it is browser independent

Comment: What output do you get in firefox?

Comment: you need to put what it does and what you want you want the output to be.

Comment: @mehulmpt I agree, but still still no output

Comment: @mehulmpt Fairly correct but if the actual issue is _different browsers send data in different ways_ (eg. checkboxes, newlines, binary data, headers etc. etc.) then it's not necessarily independent. OP: Are you certain everything is being sent/received/parsed as UTF8?

Comment: The title of your question is completely wrong. The PHP code executes on the server, it doesn't care about the browser you are using to see its output. It doesn't even need to be a browser.

Comment: @h2ooooooo yes.. it is taking UTF8